# javascript runtime error '$' is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am facing "javascript runtime error '$' is undefined" error on my ASP.Net project in visual studio 2010. I have tried so many solutions that are given here but not succeed. My code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico" /><title>
    My Website
</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript">
        function mainmenu() {
            $(" #nav ul ").css({ display: "none" });

            $(" #nav li").hover(function () {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "visible", display: "none" }).show(400);
            }
            , function () {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
            });
        }



$(document).ready(function () {
        mainmenu();
    });
</s
```

& the error message indicates last 2 lines.

Can anyone help me please? How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you get any errors trying to load jquery?

Comment: In web developer tool does it show any error..like jquery-1.3.2.min.js file not found..or anyother message?

Comment: Just for your information, jQuery 1.3.2 is **extremely** old, and probably won't work properly with some modern browsers.

Comment: No I didn't get any errors to load jquery. Thilo

Comment: When I try to login or register in the browser it takes me to my project and show the error. Sagar Shirke

Comment: Then what can I do? Pointy

Comment: I solved it by the hints given by @Pointy. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Your src is not a valid path, thus your jquery is not loading and you cannot use it as it is undefined.

1) check that your path is the CORRECT one, whether your are using a jquery file locally on your machine.

2) Please note, that your tag in not closed properly:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico" /><title>
    My Website
</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language ="javascript">
        function mainmenu() {
            $(" #nav ul ").css({ display: "none" });

            $(" #nav li").hover(function () {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "visible", display: "none" }).show(400);
            }
            , function () {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
            });
        }



$(document).ready(function () {
        mainmenu();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your jQuery is not loading (or is not downloaded in your client browser for whatever reason). All you need to do is verify if the file got downloaded without any errors in your browser. Use Chrome Developer tools and share the screenshot of what you see in Network tab. In this tab you should be able to see jquery related links as well. Check the status code

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the problem was in the ajaxtoolkit. I just replace the code "../javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" by the code  "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js". And it works. :)